# How do I make Jenkins cancel a scm-triggered build if another scm-triggered build occurred?

Tags: svn, version-control, jenkins

I have a project that takes about 15 minutes to run its build in jenkins (phpunit is the longest element of the build).

I've configured scm-triggered builds (svn based), so everytime a commit happen, a build is triggered (using a post-commit script).

However, if a commit happens while jenkins is still building the project, it is pending until the previous build finishes.
Since the old build is not relevant once a new commit has been made, how can make jenkins cancel a current build if a new build is pending for the same project ?

Comment: If you do this and there are enough scm changes you will end up with a build a day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is not bad to build project for each change set, if build failed you will know which change set requires verification.

But if you want to combine some changesets into one build I recommend to setup `Quiet period` in `Advanced Project Options` to delay builds.